# Crash / reboot on boot with Ubuntu 22.04 and AMD RX5500

Tags: crash, amdgpu

I've upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and I can't boot the system without using `nomodeset`. It hangs a while after printing the following before it reboots.

```
[amdgpu] *ERROR* ring sdma1 timeout
```

Here is a list of things I have tried without luck.

- Upgraded the kernel to 5.18.14
- Disabled wayland
- Upgraded mesa from the kisak-mesa ppa

Any ideas of how to fix this? From what I can tell there aren't any proparatry driver available anymore?

[image: bootlog]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not... swapping the hdmi cable for display port made it work just fine!

Answer (score 0):

I have running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Kernel 5.15.0-52 and switched with an existing installation (old PC) to a new system with

- Asus X670E TUF Gaming Plus Wifi
- AMD Ryzen 7 7700X with (iGPU) integrated Graphics

First my system hang on boot with out any meaningful error message.
The reason was an outdated graphics driver kernel module "amdgpu".

Try to edit kernel parameters from the grub menu with "e" and add "nomodeset" to prevent usage of "amdgpu" driver.
Like "linux /@/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-52-generic root=UUID=0....98 ro **nomodeset** splash $vt_handoff"

Using "nomodeset" I was able to boot the system normally.
Final solution is to install AMD Radeon GPU driver for Ubuntu 22.04.

Attention:

The offical linked version on AMD homepage is "Radeon Software for Linux installer version 22.20" with date 13-Jul-2022. This did not work for me.
But there is a later version on the server called "5.3" with the date 9-Sep-2022. This is working for me!

Links:

https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers
https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/
https://repo.radeon.com/amdgpu-install/5.3/ubuntu/jammy/